# Converting Ranges of Values to a new Range

Tags: python, math

So I am working on a small piece of code that involves a controller, but that isn't too important.

The problem I am having trouble with is that I am trying to convert an arbitrary number between the range of -32767 - 32768 to a range from 0 - 1.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To normalize a variable within a range, scale and shift the variable as follows:

```
amin, amax = -32767, 32768
x = (x- amin)/(amax-amin)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Would you also happen to know how to change it to a range from -1 to 1?

Comment: Replace the second line with `x = 2*(x-amin)/(amax-amin) - 1`.